# Regex string not working correctly in RegExp.test

Tags: javascript, regex

I have written a regex to match currency values with optional 2 decimal places, with either decimal point OR comma for EU.

```
^\d+((\.|,)\d{2})?$
```

The regex  works as expected in regex101 tester:
https://regex101.com/r/GrHsX0/1

But when using in javascript it's returning false regardless of match.

```
var patt = new RegExp("^\d+((\.|,)\d{2})?$");

var res1 = patt.test("11.33"); //should return true
var res2 = patt.test("22,44"); //should return true
var res3 = patt.test("abc"); //should return false
```

Here is a fiddle example:
https://jsfiddle.net/t0p4ok08/

Bit puzzled as to why this is not working! Thanks in advance.

Comment: *Double escape guys, double escape.*

Comment: and you don't need alternatives in this case. A character class does the job `^\d+(?:[.,]\d{2})?$`

Comment: You don't need a constructor, or quotes, or escaping: `var patt = /^\d+((\.|,)\d{2})?$/;`

Comment: ... only if he's going to use a *literal notation* instead. @ChrisG

Comment: Thanks for the info guys